# Texshop jump to source code not working

Tags: texshop

Just installed newest version of TeXShop on new MacBook Pro.  I cannot seem to get the editor to jump between the source and the .pdf it created.  This feature is essential to me.  I have tried every possible combination of COMMAND,SHIFT,CONTROL,OPTION,FN, and clicking, and nothing works.  Help?

Comment: I compiled anew, with a different name, a rather large project of mine and tried Command-Shift-click on both the source and the PDF file. It seems to work with no problem.

Comment: Has your synctex file been removed?